# accessing Android sensor with class extending Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

For design reason,  I  have to implement Android Sensor Specific code into the class with extends Dialog. For example,

```
public class ImplEndUserGUI extends Dialog implements IEndUserGUI {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.enduserguilayout);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //TODO : I have to write Android specific code here....
    SensorManager sensorManager = 
      (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor lightSensor = 
      sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    .....
  }
}
```

Now, the  problem is that  (with my limited knowledge of  Android programming), Android does not allow me use `getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)` with a `ImplEndUserGUI` **`extends Dialog`**. Could you please suggest me the way of implementing Android access code with a class of `extends Dialog`.

Comment: Is there a reason why getContext().getSystemService... not work?

Comment: because the ImplEndUSerGUI class is extended with Dialog.

Comment: I must be confused. android.app.Dialog? What about this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#getContext()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constructor with Context param

```
public ImplEndUserGUI(Context context) {
     mContext = context;
     }
```

Then you can get SensorManager using

```
SensorManager  sensorManager =  (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can almost always use

```
SensorManager sensorManager = 
  (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```